# How to Add empty option on ng-select dropdown for custom ng-template?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, angular-ngselect

I'm using ng-select in the Angular 9 version, I need to show the title on hover so I implemented a title like this ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-yeyqdi )

here title issue is resolved but I need to show first empty option with a title also
it is possible on ng-select? please help me guys

expected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMhRw.png)

Comment: Can you tell more about "first empty option with a title" ? like this?
<empty>
item 1
item 3
item 3

Comment: Do you want to show the first item on default or some message with "Select Title" on default?

Comment: I need one empty option at first,  in the empty option title is not required. in other option required title on hover u can see this image for reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMhRw.png

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can get it using css [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

```
.ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items .ng-option:first-child {
    color: transparent!important;
}
```

**Important!**: You need include in your styles.scss -not in component-

Another option is create a "special" item

```
new Model('my title', ['empty']),
```

And use

```
<ng-select [items]="myList"
            bindLabel="name"
            [searchFn]="customSearch">
            <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm">
              <ng-container *ngIf="item.tags[0]=='empty'">
                 <span style="display:inline-block;width:100%" [title]="item.name">
                    &nbsp;
                 </span>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf="item.tags[0]!='empty'">
              <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search" [title]="item.name">
                {{item.name}}
              </span>
              </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-jjjqu5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) with the two options

Comment: Thanks! Eliseo,  for spending time to solve an issue 
I check your example but there is the first option I selected is selecting 'item 1'
it should be blank.

Comment: @Mitul, if you use "css" the first element of myList is not visible (It doesn't matter whatever value was, -just add a item with the value you need to make it-). If you create an "especial item" (the other option I suggest), is the special item -in the position you put- the element not visible